# Retrieving data from a second table if it has a record with the Id from another table

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 context tables and I would like to select data from them if the ids are equal.

I would like to do this using LINQ's fluent API.

I want to check if the `Id` in `Movie` equals the `MovieId` in `MovieReview`, and if so present the `ReviewerName` from `MovieReview`, and `Name` from `Movie`

The tables are:

```
public class MovieReview
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Range(1,10)]
    [Required]
    public int Rating { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(1024)]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="User Name")]
    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText="anonymous")]
    public string ReviewerName { get; set; }
    public int MovieId { get; set; }


public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Director { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MovieReview> Reviews { get; set; }
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

So far I made.. not even sure if im close:
var model =
                _db.Movies
                .Join(_db.Reviews, g => g.Id, u => u.MovieId, (g,u) => new { MovieReview = u, Movie = g})
                .Where( (g => g.Movie 
                select (r => new AdminReviewListViewModels
                {
                    Id = g.Id,
                    Name = g.Name,
                    Director = g.Director,
                    ReleaseDate = g.ReleaseDate,
                    Genre = g.Genre,
                    CountOfReviews = g.Reviews.Count(),
                    UserName = u.ReviewerName
                });

Comment: Since `Movie` has `ICollection<MovieReview>`, why would you need to match? Wouldn't `movie.Reviews` get you all `MovieReview`s associated?

Comment: Are you using the entity framework or is this just a set of POCO's you've built?

Comment: I am using entity framework yes, ICollection is just to have a collection of reviews, I set the Id in "Movie" and, the MovieId in MovieReview so that in future i could do this kind of compare between the tables. so far I have: var model =
_db.Movies
.Join(_db.Reviews, g => g.Id, u => u.MovieId, (g,u) => new { MovieReview = u, Movie = g})
.Where( (g => g.Movie 
select (r => new AdminReviewListViewModels
{
Id = g.Id,
Name = g.Name,
Director = g.Director,
ReleaseDate = g.ReleaseDate,
Genre = g.Genre,
CountOfReviews = g.Reviews.Count(),
 UserName = u.ReviewerName
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need an anonymous enumerable that contains MovieName and ReviewerName properties, this should work.

```
using (var _db = new YourDbContext())
{
    var movies = _db.Movies;
    var movieReviews = _db.MovieReviews;

    var results = movies.Join(movieReviews, 
        m => m.Id,
        mr => mr.MovieId,
        (m, mr) => new { MovieName = m.Name, ReviewerName = mr.ReviewerName }).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
context.Set<MovieReview>().Select(c=>new{c.ReviewerName, c.Movie.Name})
```